# Solving first order DE by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following DE:

$$(x+ye^{y/x})dx - xe^{y/x} dy = 0$$

I want to sub in $ u = \frac yx $
. When I solve for and take the derivative of $y=ux$,  I get $dy = xdu + u$. Is this right? I am also wondering if I can write it as $\frac {dy}{dx} = x\frac {du}{dx} + u$? My last question is could I have solved for x and solved for $dx$?

Thank you.

Comment: how about my last question? @Moo

Comment: I have another question: My friend is subbing y = ux and saying that $dy = xdu + udx$ but I thought dx  = x. Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x+ye^{y/x})dx - xe^{y/x} dy = 0$$
$$(x+ye^{y/x}) = xe^{y/x}y'$$
$$(\frac y x+e^{-y/x}) = y'$$
$$y'=(\frac y x+e^{-y/x})$$
substitute $y=tx$ and $y'=t'x+t$ 
$$t'x+t=t+e^{-t}$$
$$t'x=e^{-t}$$
It's seperable now
$$\int e^t dt=\int \frac {dx} x=\ln(x)+K$$
$$ e^t =\ln(x)+K$$
$$ e^{y/x} =\ln(x)+K \implies e^y=(\ln(x)+K)^x$$
$$y=\ln(\ln(x)+K)^x=x\ln(\ln(x)+K)$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=x\ln(\ln(x)+K)}$$

Comment: Could you show me if I were to divide by x first and then use u = y/x? Thank you.

Comment: @Kovs95 I simplified the equation first then i used substitution like $y=ux$ but used t in place of u bit its the same